# Drop duplicates but keep rows having largest value in a given column per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a DF like this:

```
    Name        Gender         Age      Level
  Pikachu        Male           4         8
 Charmander     Female          5         7
 Charmander     Female          5         7
 Squirtle        Male           3         6
 Squirtle        Male           3         9
 Squirtle       Female          4         9
```

I want it to look like this:

```
   Name        Gender         Age      Level
  Pikachu        Male           4         8
 Charmander     Female          5         7
 Squirtle        Male           3         9
 Squirtle       Female          4         9
```

I don't know how to explain what I want to do in English so I'll write it in pseudocode.

Basically:

```
If Name, Gender and Age are the same:
      If there is a difference in levels:
            Keep the row with higher level
      If there is a tie:
            Keep a random one
```

Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `argsort` and `duplicated`:

```
df[~df.iloc[np.argsort(-df.Level)].drop('Level', 1).duplicated()]

         Name  Gender  Age  Level
0     Pikachu    Male    4      8
1  Charmander  Female    5      7
4    Squirtle    Male    3      9
5    Squirtle  Female    4      9
```

---

`groupby` + `idxmax` solution (although slower):

```
df.iloc[df.groupby(['Name','Gender', 'Age']).Level.idxmax()]

         Name  Gender  Age  Level
1  Charmander  Female    5      7
0     Pikachu    Male    4      8
5    Squirtle  Female    4      9
4    Squirtle    Male    3      9
```

Comment: I think also can using idxmax :-)

Comment: I like the groupby + idmax solution, much more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Check with `sort_values`+`drop_duplicates`

```
df=df.sort_values('Level').drop_duplicates(['Name','Gender','Age'],keep='last')
df
         Name  Gender  Age  Level
2  Charmander  Female    5      7
0     Pikachu    Male    4      8
4    Squirtle    Male    3      9
5    Squirtle  Female    4      9
```